# Ember-cli creates/initializes app.js twice

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-app-kit, broccolijs

I'm moving my project from Ember AppKit to Ember-Cli. I have an myapp/app/app.js, where the app is initialized and in myapp/app/index.html I have the following lines:

```
        var config = require('myapp/config/environment')['default'];
        window.App = require('myapp/app')["default"].create(config.APP);
```

*config is not that important in my question.

So when I run the ember server I see that app.js was called twice. For the first time, automatically, I guess, and the second call is made by create() function from above. So after running the server I get an error:

*"Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot use the same root element (body) multiple times in an Ember.Application "*

I know that the error means that I'm creating two instances of my app in the same DOM-Object and it can be solved by creating two sub containers () with different ids.

**But how do I avoid creating the first instance, which is done automatically, before I actually call create()?** Without the lines shown above the app is not shown at all, but with them I get the mentioned error. I have checked the whole app implementation, there is nothing what would call the  initial instance creation, before create() function from above.

I didn't have that mistake in EmberAppKit running Grunt

Answer (score 1):

In Ember CLI config lives in `/config/environment.js`, and it will be handed to your app automatically. You shouldn't need to this manually.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. But not adding config in create() doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you try to make a clean ember-cli app and see how it handles config? Try that and compare to what you have.

Comment: Thankx! I've checked, I think in Ember-Cli we shouldn't set window. App in index.

Answer (score 0):

Setting window.App=this in app.js has solved the problem.

If you look into my-app.js in assets, you will see that an instance is created at the end of the script.  So it only has to be assigned to window.App